# c# alternative for enum to get intellisense advantages

Tags: c#

I have a base class

```
abstract public class ComponentBase
{
    public List<string> Actions { get; set; }

    protected abstract void RegisterActions();
}
```

and its child

```
public class VideoBase : ComponentBase
{
    protected override void RegisterActions()
    {
        base.Actions.Add("Start video");
        base.Actions.Add("Pause video");
        base.Actions.Add("Rewind video");
    }
}
```

But to make things easier i also create enum type

```
public enum Actions
{
    START_VIDEO,
    PAUSE_VIDEO,
    REWIND_VIDEO,
}
```

What i want is to force every child of ComponentBase to have its own enum Actions but it seems its not easy to do. Alternatively i though about changing Actions List to `Dictionary<string, string>`but it doesn't give me intellisense advantage. I want for user of this class to easily get "list" of actions in intellisense, instead of checking what string value they have to put, any suggestions?

Comment: Unless you know in the base class every possible action the derived types might need, you can't really enforce what you want. But why do you want to force anyone to do anything? Let the implementors of the derived types do whatever they decide is comfortable for them. No one is stopping them from creating a static private class with all the required strings as constants, an enum or whatever if they wish.

Comment: If you've access to the base class you may want to try a class with constant properties.

Comment: Documentation Comments is the closest thing you can do to get the list's info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using generics in your base class?

```
abstract public class ComponentBase<T> where T : struct
{
    //Example property.
    public T Action { get; set; }
}
```

> As [InBetween](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767890) mentioned, in C# 7.3 you can add an additional constraint to force the generic type to be an enum:
>
> ```
> abstract public class ComponentBase<T> where T : struct, System.Enum
> ```

That way you get to specify which enum to use when inheriting `ComponentBase` in your child class:

```
public class VideoBase : ComponentBase<VideoActions>
{
    ...your code...
}

public enum VideoActions
{
    START_VIDEO,
    PAUSE_VIDEO,
    REWIND_VIDEO
}
```

```
VideoBase video = new VideoBase();

//video.Action will now be of type VideoActions.
video.Action = VideoActions.START_VIDEO;
```

Comment: In the latest language version you can actually constraint `T` to `enum`.

Comment: @InBetween : Thanks! Didn't know that!

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to have this `enum`-like implementation to restrict the value to a specific subset of string values, there is a solution for this. You could create a class with private constructor and static fields:

```
public class Action
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Start video
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Action START_VIDEO = new Action("Start video");

    /// <summary>
    /// Pause video
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Action PAUSE_VIDEO = new Action("Pause video");

    /// <summary>
    /// Rewind video
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Action REWIND_VIDEO = new Action("Rewind video");


    private readonly string _value;

    private Action(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Action action)
    {
        return action._value;
    }
}
```

And whenever you restrict any input to `Action`, like your list for example

```
public List<Action> Actions { get; set; }
```

or something like

```
public void RegisterAction(Action action) { }
```

Which will restrict the value to one of those declared in the `Action` class rather than allowing any `string` to be used.

You can then do the `Actions.Add(<intellisense suggestions show up>)`
[image]

and still use it as `string` within your code if needed:

```
// Implicit conversion
string someValue = Action.START_VIDEO;

// .ToString() override
Console.WriteLine("Action: " + Action.START_VIDEO);
```

In both cases the code will use the string representation declared in the class instead of the name as it would be in `enum` case.

Furthermore, by providing the description in `<summary>` you also get the advantage of seeing the actual value when hovering mouse over reference to `Action`.

Comment: *This way you can use it both as `Action` and as `string`, that is, you can have both*. A `List<Action>` and a `List<string`> are absolutely *not* the same thing and one can not be converted to the other. `List<T>` is invariant in `T`; first because its a class, not an interface, and second because the type parameter can`t be covariant or contravariant.

Comment: @InBetween I didn't say it's the same, what I meant is that `Actions.Add(Action.START_VIDEO)` will work in both cases `List<Action>` and `List<string>`. In the latter case, implicit cast would be used which I declared in the example.

Comment: But if the ultimate goal is to register in `List<string> Actions` then why all this unnecessary boiler plate? What does this provide that simple constant strings declared in the derived type don't?

Comment: @InBetween that's actually a good point. If it's not restricted as `Action` anywhere in the code, then there's no advantage of this example in comparison with string constants except for maybe having control of values if they are referenced outside of the library which I don't really think is needed in this case anyways.